# What do I do when APT (or another process in a terminal) seemingly stalls on an empty line?

Tags: command-line, apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As an Ubuntu newbie, I'm always lost with what to do when *this* happens...

[image: reading package lists... done. then nothing]

The progress appears to be stalled, but there's nothing on the current line to show me what might be happening that could stall... it's just a blank line and a blinking cursor, and the last line said it was 'done'.

It has been on this for like 15 minutes now, but this hasn't been the first time, and sometimes it eventually does something afterward. As well as in this specific situation, how am I supposed to know what to do whenever this kind of thing happens in Ubuntu? Is there a best practice or something? One of these times I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'d and then ran the command again waited longer, and it actually finished doing the thing. This time I don't seem to be having much success no matter how long I wait.

All my experience with Windows and CentOS hasn't ever prepared me for these situations and I really want to finally `apt-get` Ubuntu this time.

**EDIT:** I forgot as I am so used to using CentOS over SSH and it feels virtually the same for the most part, but technically I'm not running "pure" Ubuntu, I'm running it via the Windows Linux Subsystem... so perhaps that is to blame for everything. Still, I figured it would be *easier* than trying to get Ubuntu set up as an entire OS, not harder...

Comment: That output is from `sudo apt update`, I guess? The next line to expect would be "Building dependency tree". What I would try first is deleting and re-downloading all  package lists: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists ; sudo apt update`. That should help if any of your current lists got corrupt somehow and is causing this. Another thing you could try is to run `sudo dpkg --audit` to perform some database sanity checks, but I doubt this would return anything. Also, does it make a difference whether you use `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: It was `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` I believe, and I was following a guide for installing postgresql... so perhaps it may have been stalled between the two (assuming there was nothing left for the update command)? I've only ever used `apt-get` so far as I figured it was the synonymous command of `yum` from CentOS. It may be important to note that this isn't a "pure" Ubuntu build as it's running it in the Windows Linux Subsystem (which I actually forgot as I'm so used to using CentOS via SSH), so every command I attempt to run seems to require extra consideration...

Comment: As far as installation from remote repositories, apt and yum are the same. That's not the issue.  As you see, it's done reading packages, so we can rule out that as an issue, but then it's probably taking long time to calculate updates size. I wouldn't worry about this too much. Either let the command finish or restart it.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy OK, maybe I'm just being overly cautious. The first time I had to totally reinstall Ubuntu* (*on Windows) because an install failed and I was completely unable to get any further installs/removes/cleans working. Fortunately I wasn't so far in so resetting seemed like the best option. Earlier I had an internet disconnect during an `apt-get install` and had to use `--fix-missing` (?) to complete it, though I couldn't find any online confirmation that it was the correct method.

Comment: @Deji  `--fix-missing` is the correct method, which works most times, although there are times when you have to trace which packages need fixing manually. Unfortunately, remote package managers in general can break, be it `yum` or `apt` - doesn't matter.

Comment: @Deji Btw, here's a suggestion:   the next time the command stalls, try finding out its PID and then look at what the process is doing via `sudo strace -p <PID>`. The `strace` utility shows low level system calls being executed for a process. I use it for troubleshooting processes that have high CPU usage sometimes.  You could also specify `-o file.txt` where to save the output, so next time you could paste that file and maybe someone can help you see  what's actually happening

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I think that's exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for, some way to check what it's doing without just cancelling or waiting for something to happen, so thanks! Unfortunately all the guides I follow seem to omit what to do when things unexpectedly go wrong.

Comment: @Deji  There's plenty of things that can go wrong. And besides all the guides focus on the basics. In any case, you're welcome, and feel free to ask other questions if you run into any trouble. I can convert my previous comment into an actual answer, but then again it's very incomplete. Just next time it happens, try the suggestion and we'll see what can be done.

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Comment: @KarlRichter I provided both. The image is of a blank line/blinking cursor so it can't exactly just be text, I provided both text and a description of what it was.

Comment: @Deji The visualization of the blinking cursor isn't necessary because it's present no matter whether the command would make progress or not. The combination of the output in the image (provided as text which you didn't do) and words describing it ("stalled", etc.) are helpful for others searching for a solution to the same problem in a search engine.

Comment: @KarlRichter The output in the image was nothing to do with my *question*. I never asked about the text. I asked what to do in cases where Ubuntu stalls on a empty line with a blinking cursor - I *know* it can be present whether the command would make progress or not, I made that point myself in the question. My question was literally regarding what to do in this situation where I'm left with no clue whether there will be progress or not. All I felt was relevant in the image I detailed very well in the paragraph right below it.

Comment: Does "(or another process in a terminal)" mean it's the same for `cat`?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I assume so, the title was edited though... as well as the body, having "afterwards" changed to "afterward" even though a quick Google search says both are valid but my spellcheck says the latter is not even a word *\*shrugs\**. Free for all!

Comment: Welcome here! Yes, they seem to be the same - maybe it is different in US vs British English? It was not me. Strange - maybe somebody tested it? By the way, there is a full edit history, look at the link below the q in the middle...

Answer (score 0):

I would check the `/var/log/apt/term.log`. This is the default location for the `apt-get` log.

Next, but this is what @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy  already mentioned I would use the 
`strace`¹ to check what exactly is happening in here.

Probable I would use, `apt-get update` and check what will happen, then I will do the `apt-get upgrade`.

Hopefully this all makes sense.

You can also use `strace -p` to check the process and `strace -o` to a file.

¹ <sub>strace apt-get update</sub>